# I would like my javascript quiz to show different choices for each individual question

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a workoutcalculator that depending on what the user choices to select as their awnswer will generate a specific workout for them.

I am trying to create the quiz so that each question has a different number of answers for example their age is going to be roughly 5-6 different answers and their sex is of course only going to be 2.

what is this best method for getting this working?

Please forgive my awful code this is my first heavy project using javascript!

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Work Out Programme</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <!--Start of Work out Calculator-->
    <div id="start">Start your workout journey</div>
    <!--Quiz Container-->
    <div id="quiz" style="display: none;">
        <div id="question">
            <p> Question </p>
        </div>
        <!--Choices Containers-->

        <!--Male or female Question-->
        <div id="choices1">
            <div class="choiceA1" id="A1" onclick="checkAnswer('A1')"></div>
            <div class="choiceB1" id="B1" onclick="checkAnswer('B1')"></div>
        </div>
        <!--Your age Question-->
        <div id="choices2">
            <div class="choiceA2" id="A2" onclick="checkAnswer('A2')"></div>
            <div class="choiceB2" id="B2" onclick="checkAnswer('B2')"></div>
            <div class="choiceC2" id="C2" onclick="checkAnswer('C2')"></div>
            <div class="choiceD2" id="D2" onclick="checkAnswer('D2')"></div>
            <div class="choiceE2" id="E2" onclick="checkAnswer('E2')"></div>
            <div class="choiceF2" id="F2" onclick="checkAnswer('F2')"></div>
        </div>
        <!--Male current condition Question-->
        <div id="choices3">
            <div class="choiceA3" id="A3" onclick="checkAnswer('A3')"></div>
            <div class="choiceB3" id="B3" onclick="checkAnswer('B3')"></div>
            <div class="choiceC3" id="C3" onclick="checkAnswer('C3')"></div>
            <div class="choiceD3" id="D3" onclick="checkAnswer('D3')"></div>
        </div>

        <!--Female current condition Question-->
        <div id="choices4">
            <div class="choiceA4" id="A4" onclick="checkAnswer('A4')"></div>
            <div class="choiceB4" id="B4" onclick="checkAnswer('B4')"></div>
            <div class="choiceC4" id="C4" onclick="checkAnswer('C4')"></div>
        </div>


        <!--all the choices need to be unique as every quesiton is going to have a different number of question and answers this is so that depending on what the user choices it will match their choice -->


    </div>
    <!--Score Container-->
    <div id="scoreContainer" style="display: none;"></div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="./app.js"></script>

</html>



const start = document.getElementById("start");
const quiz = document.getElementById("quiz");
const question = document.getElementById("question");
const scoreContainer = document.getElementById("scoreContainer");

// this is where I need to pull all the choices from the html document and then get them to run and return something based on what has been chosen i also need to figure out if i need to pull every single on or just the id for example more invesitgating is needed 
/*const choiceA = document.getElementById("A");
const choiceB = document.getElementById("B");
const choiceC = document.getElementById("C");
*/

// Pulling through the questions for choice 1 Male or female Question
const choiceA1 = document.getElementById('A1');
const choiceB1 = document.getElementById('B1');

// Pulling through the questions for choice 2 Your age Question

const choiceA2 = document.getElementById('A2');
const choiceB2 = document.getElementById('B2');
const choiceC2 = document.getElementById('C2');
const choiceD2 = document.getElementById('D2');
const choiceE2 = document.getElementById('E2');
const choiceF2 = document.getElementById('F2');


// Pulling through the questions for choice 3 Male current condition Question

const choiceA3 = document.getElementById('A3');
const choiceB3 = document.getElementById('B3');
const choiceC3 = document.getElementById('C3');
const choiceD3 = document.getElementById('D3');


// Pulling through the questions for choice 4 Female current condition Question

const choiceA4 = document.getElementById('A4');
const choiceB4 = document.getElementById('B4');
const choiceC4 = document.getElementById('C4');





// Questions for the quiz

let questions = [

    {
        question: "What is your sex?",
        choiceA1: "Male",
        choiceB1: "Female",
        //correct  //need to figure out later
    },

    {
        question: "What is your age range?",
        choiceA2: "Teens",
        choiceB2: "20's",
        choiceC2: "30's",
        choiceD2: "40's",
        choiceE2: "50's",
        choiceF2: "60+",
        //correct //need to figure out later
    },

    {
        question: "Please select the best description of your current condition:",
        choiceA3: "I have low levels of body fat, I can see my abs, and I want to build more muscle",
        choiceB3: "I'm 'skinny fat' I look skinny and definitely need more muscle, but I still have fat covering my abs",
        choiceC3: "I have a good level of muscle size, but I need to drop fat to reveal muscle definition and six pack abs",
        choiceD3: "I have no clue how much muscle I have with all this fat covering it I need to loose a bunch of fat!",
        //correct //need to figure out later
    },

    {
        question: "Please Select The Best Description of Your Current Physique:",
        choiceA4: "I have a slim body type and want to gain muscle in the right areas to look my best",
        choiceB4: "I have stubborn body fat. I want to slim down and increase my muscle tone",
        choiceC4: "I have more than 10kg of fat to lose - I want to drop all this fat and look my best",
        //correct //need to figure out later
    }

];


// Create some variables 

const lastQuestion = questions.length - 1;
let runningQuestion = 0;

// run a question 

function runQuestion() {
    let q = questions[runningQuestion];

    question.innerHTML = "<p>" + q.question + "</p>";
    choiceA1.innerHTML = q.choiceA1;
    choiceB1.innerHTML = q.choiceB1;
    choiceA2.innerHTML = q.choiceA2;

}

start.style.display = "none";
runQuestion();
quiz.style.display = "block";
```

Comment: gender, these days is more than 2 options ;-)

Comment: You have used function checkAnswer() but didn't define it.

Comment: For analysing the answers I Prefer nested parent and child which parent has `data-question="1"` and answers have `data-answer="1"` and `data-answer="2"` etc. You wont need define click listener on each answer. just use a global function to  save selected answer and its parent data.